Angular Login Form with Backend in Spring
I'm creating simple angular app with a backend Java Spring.
These are two standalone projects.
I'm going to create login form in Angular. I see many tutorials on the internet
where basic authentication is being used for the authentication in an angular app.
But couldn't find anything with standard form login authentication where username and password is being send in JSON body.
1)
Is it recommended way to do it as a base authentication when we compare it with standard form authentication?
Best,

The password should not be sent in the JSON body. Usually, username and password get base64-encoded and send in the 'Authorization' request header.
In principle, there is nothing wrong with Basic Authentication and form inputs.
You may want to follow this tutorial: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2022/12/27/angular-14-basic-authentication-tutorial-with-example

Can I create a custom login form and send data as a x-www-form-urlencoded to my server in Java Spring and be have a cookie session in my browser returned by this server, so then I'll be logged in? Keeping in mind the server and client are two different projects / on two different domains.
Sorry I'm trying to understand Spring Security.

Look at this piece of documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/form.html. It describes basic auth with a (custom) form. In the end the session strategy is mentioned. Maybe this is what you are looking for.

The part with remember me services could be interesting, too.
